# Error :Failed to start javac.exe. exec: "javac.exe": executable file not found in %PATH after running a gauge command on intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javac, gauge

I m trying to run this command in IntelliJ IDE and got an error
`gauge validate specs/install/installation.spec`

```
Failed to start javac.exe. exec: "javac.exe": executable file not found in %PATH%
Error ----------------------------------

Failed to start gauge API: Runner with pid 22600 quit unexpectedly(exit status 1).
```

I have Java on my machine, but still where I should configure it in IntelliJ?

> project settings>Platform settings>SDK

Comment: Do you have `JAVA_HOME\bin` in `PATH`? Can you run `java.exe` from `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Yes i have JAVA_HOME\bin and also can run java.exe